# How can i avoid decimal values with input from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, input, int, decimal, material-ui

I have tried the usual ways that work in normal `HTML inputs`, but none seems to work in my code, i can still type , and . on the `input`.

Here is my code now :

```
<div className={classes.container} >
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} >
    <InputLabel htmlFor="name-simple" >{text}</InputLabel>
    <Input onChange={this.handleChange} id={X} key={X} name={Text} 
                             min="1" step="1" type="number" />
    </FormControl>
</div>
```

How can i just acept `int` on this input?

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
class Lucio extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            textVal: ''
        };
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            textVal: Math.floor(Number(e))
        });  
    };
    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return(
            <div className={classes.container} >
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl} >
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="name-simple" >{text}</InputLabel>
                    <Input onChange={this.handleChange} id={X} key={X} name={Text} min="1" step="1" type="number" value={this.state.textVal} />
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work with mui v5 any more. Property `min` and `step` are not part of `Input` anymore.